# Identify two structs in IDA

Tags: ida, struct

When decompiling an exe file, I have defined two structs `struct A` and `struct B` that are of the same structure. They appeared under different contexts, thus I assumed that they were different structs. However, as the contexts merge, I realize that these are in fact the same struct.

Now I would like to get rid of `struct B` and replace all its occurance with `struct A`. Is it possible to do that without manually changing everything?

I know that I can define `struct B` as containing just one `struct A` as its member, but this feels less optimal and creates unnecessary syntax in decompiled code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that through the "local types" window (`View -> Open subviews -> Local types`). Right-click on the structure and select `Map to another type`.

Comment: Thank you , this works fine.